# How to monitor network status change in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There are two event listeners that are apparently useful when to monitor the network status:

```
1. window.addEventListener('online', console.log('Online'));
2. window.addEventListener('offline', console.log('Offline'));
```

But I am not sure where to register and use them. When I use them within `componentDidMount`, there is no use because monitoring would happen only if the component is mounted. I want to monitor the network status in one place and use it across the application. For this, dispatching the network status in redux would be more helpful. But the problem is where to listen for this events.

Comment: How about setting the listener in `App.js componentDidMount()`? On it's callback you can call a redux action to store the data in any way you like. Don't forget to store the reference in order to clear it on unMount.

Comment: This answer is going to be big.  Basically have the root container start listening when it mounts, And dispatch actions to your redux store to indicate when network status changes.  What parts of this will you need explained?

Comment: @Wyck For example, if the network connectivity is lost when i'm using the application, can I detect it?. In this scenario, `componentDidMount` is not triggered for root container.

Comment: Would [react-detect-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-detect-offline) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this [very new library](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/react-adaptive-hooks)

Then you can use `useNetworkStatus` to get what you wanted, something like:

```
import React from 'react';

import { useNetworkStatus } from 'react-adaptive-hooks/network';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { effectiveConnectionType } = useNetworkStatus();

  let media;
  switch(effectiveConnectionType) {
    case 'slow-2g':
      media = <img src='...' alt='low resolution' />;
      break;
    case '2g':
      media = <img src='...' alt='medium resolution' />;
      break;
    case '3g':
      media = <img src='...' alt='high resolution' />;
      break;
    case '4g':
      media = <video muted controls>...</video>;
      break;
    default:
      media = <video muted controls>...</video>;
      break;
  }

  return <div>{media}</div>;
};
```

`effectiveConnectionType` - will change if the network changes, `

`navigator.connection.addEventListener('change', func)` - this will also get trigger on `online` and on `offline`

Comment: `effectiveConnectionType` does NOT actually detect offline status. It reports the effective connection type, but does NOT monitor connectivity itself. See this issue: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/react-adaptive-hooks/issues/35

Comment: Its going in infinite loop, Can you please check [THIS issue](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/react-adaptive-hooks/issues/77) I'm getting

Answer (score 2):

Simplified example with class components:

```
// In your main App component
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('online', () => this.props.setConnectivity('online'));
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => this.props.setConnectivity('offline'));

    // You don't need to worry about removeEventlistener if your main App component never unmounts.
}

// Action
const setConnectivity = (status) => ({
    type: 'SET_CONNECTIVITY',
    payload: status === 'online'
})

// Reducer
const connectivityReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_CONNECTIVITY':
            return {
                ...state,
                isOnline: action.payload
            };
    }
};

// To let a component know about the connectivity status, simply use the flag from state:
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isOnline: state.connectivity.isOnline
});

// To react to status changes in any other component:
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { isOnline } = this.props;

    if (!prevProps.isOnline && isOnline) {
        // We went online
    } else if (prevProp.isOnline && !isOnline) {
        // We went offline
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of an *online / offline* status indicator in React+Redux.

The magic comes from having a component that adds an event listener for the `online` event in the component's `componentDidMount` event.  Then it dispatches an action via Redux to update the online status in the store.  A container component (`MainContainer` in this example) can map the global store state to props, and any presentational component can update in response to this property changing.

By the way, if you want to test this online indicator on this page with Chrome: run the snippet, then launch the Dev Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), then toggle the device toolbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) (or 2nd icon in the top left of the dev tools window), switch to *Responsive* layout, and toggle the *Online / Offline* state in the bar (as shown in this picture) as desired:

[image: Chrome's device toolbar]

```js
function rootReducer(currentState, action) {
  currentState = currentState || { status: true }; // Initial State

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ONLINE_STATUS':
      return { ...currentState, status: action.status };
    default:
      return currentState; // Always return the state
  }
}

// Action Creators:
function setOnlineStatus(status) {
  return { type: 'SET_ONLINE_STATUS', status };
}

// Create Store
var rootStore = Redux.createStore(rootReducer);

// Map state and dispatch to props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    status: state.status
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({
    setOnlineStatus: setOnlineStatus
  }, dispatch);
}

// Connection indicator pure functional presentational component
var ConnectionIndicator = (props) => {
  return (<div>You are: {props.status ? 'online' : 'offline'}</div>);
};

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<div>
      <ConnectionIndicator status={this.props.status} />
    </div>);
  }
});

var OnlineWatcher = React.createClass({
  render() { return null; },
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('online', () => {
      this.props.setOnlineStatus(true);
    })
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
      this.props.setOnlineStatus(false);
    })
  }
});


// Container components (Pass props into presentational component)
var MainContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
var OnlineWatcherContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps,
                                                mapDispatchToProps)(OnlineWatcher);

// Top-Level Component
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainContainer />
        <OnlineWatcherContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// Render to DOM
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider; // Injects store into context of all descendents
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={rootStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.5.2/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.13.0/polyfill.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- Yield to React -->
</div>
```

**NOTE:** In production code, you should also unsubscribe from the `online` and `offline` events in the `componentWillUnmount` function.

<sub>*I used [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hganz/gk9kaopr/) as a starting point.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Before all, you should have redux store with actions and reducers.You are able to connect every component you want to store and use this source of truth. You can find documentations and exampel here https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start

Actually you can find example of using online status [Integrating Navigator.onLine into React-Redux](https://medium.com/@DominicScanlan/integrating-navigator-online-into-react-redux-bf2bcf2d4f1f)

Answer (score 0):

when using hooks, this simple solution would work https://github.com/saulpalv/useOnline

```
npm i @saulpalv/useonline
```

use like this

```
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { useOnline } from '@saulpalv/useonline';

export const DialogNetwork: FC = ()=> {

    const isOnline = useOnline();

    return (
        <Dialog show={!isOnline}>
            You are not online
        </Dialog >
    );
});
```